# How can I delete multiple character strings in a column and replace it with date

Tags: r, date, character, converters

I have a date column that has values like this: `2003MM01`, `2003MM02`, `2003MM03`
As you can guess `MM01` stand for first month and `MM02` for second month, etc.. If I look at the structure from my dataframe it says the date column is a character. I want my date column like this.

```
date column
2003-01-01
2003-02-01
2003-03-01
2003-04-01
2003-05-01
```

I also have to mention my date column has multiple years with the same character string, so `2004MM01`, `2005MM01`, etc.. Any idea how to replace the character strings with the correct date? and also convert the date column from character to date?

Answer (score 1):

```r
vec <- c("2003MM01", "2003MM02", "2003MM03", "2004MM01", "2005MM01")
as.Date(gsub("MM(.*)$", "-\\1-01", vec))
# [1] "2003-01-01" "2003-02-01" "2003-03-01" "2004-01-01" "2005-01-01"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this `base R` approach also using `paste0()` to add the day and then using `as.Date()` to transform to date. Here the code:

```
#Data
df <- data.frame(date=c('2003MM01', '2003MM02', '2003MM03'),stringsAsFactors = F)
#Format date
df$Col1 <- as.Date(paste0(df$date,'01'),'%YMM%m%d')
```

Output:

```
      date       Col1
1 2003MM01 2003-01-01
2 2003MM02 2003-02-01
3 2003MM03 2003-03-01
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `ymd` from `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
library(stringr)
ymd(str_remove(vec, "MM"), truncated = 2)
#[1] "2003-01-01" "2003-02-01" "2003-03-01" "2004-01-01" "2005-01-01"
```

#### data

```
vec <- c("2003MM01", "2003MM02", "2003MM03", "2004MM01", "2005MM01")
```